# mdfind -onlyin wildcard without pipe

Tags: command-line, spotlight, path

Can `-onlyin` contain wildcards?

```
mdfind pattern -onlyin '*bin'
```

I know this works:

```
mdfind pattern | grep bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, mdfind's `-onlyin` does not perform pathname expansion nor tilde expansion and only accepts explicit pathnames. You can have multiple `-onlyin` options.

Comment: stackexchange `ls` in context of **shell** **expanstion** https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/the-result-of-ls-ls-and-ls the `*` is actually the shell (zsh or bash) expanding. So splat (*) is preformed by the shell, then what ever is expanded by the shell is passed to `mdfind`

Comment: @wrothe- not when the * is quoted